# Sub-domain iframe content access code is not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, iframe

AFAIK we cannot access the DOM content of iframe which has been loaded from different domain. But  in my case I have a website with below name

```
 http://dom1.myMainDomain.com/******
```

In that page I am loading one HTML file from sub-domain into an Iframe in above website which is sub-domain of as above. i.e

```
 http://dom2.myMainDomain.com/******/1.html
```

I have tried below code but it is not working

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var str = "http://dom1.myMainDomain.com/*****Images/";
    $('body').append('<iframe id="ifr" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%" src="' + str + $('#htmNum').val() + '.html"></iframe>');
    document.domain = "myMainDomain.com";
    $('#ifr').load(function () {
        $('#ifr').contents().find('body').html('Hey, i`ve changed content of <body>! Yay!!!');
    });
});
```

But it did not work for me.. and The web site where I am embedding the above code is

```
http://dom2.myMainDomain.com/*****.aspx
```

`Please help me on this. As per the answer I have tried and it was working in IE7./ But in Chrome I can see permission denied message`

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364776/can-i-access-contents-of-an-iframe-from-a-subdomain-if-i-use-www-on-the-main-do)

Comment: @FAngel I am still unable to access it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must do `document.domain = "myMainDomain.com";` in both paretnt page and here `http://dom1.myMainDomain.com/*****Images/`. Your document ready function is Ok, but you also should have similar piece of code in here `http://dom1.myMainDomain.com/*****Images/`. I would place it in head section like

```
<head>
<script type="text/javscript">
   document.domain = "myMainDomain.com";
</script>
</head>
```

And suppose it would be better to move put the same code in head of parent document. Just to be sure that everything is set correctly in when you access an iframe

Yeah. Just double checked it. I can access an iframe content with code like this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body")
```

if in both parent window and iframe there is `document.domain = "com.local";` in javascript

Comment: Oh, Thanks I will try doing this.

Comment: I've been checking it in Chrome.

Comment: @SoI I mean that while double checking I were using chrome

Comment: it is saying protocol, domain, port must match

Comment: Where you put a document.domain line?

Comment: I had put it in head of iframe file and main html file

Comment: @SoI Cool. I just got the same error even having domain set, but it missed after I updated iframe src from http://rf.com.local/reports to http://rf.com.local/reports/ (and now I can't reproduce it again). Creasy idea, but maybe cache? Chrome has a really strong caching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are on the same domain, try this:

```
var iframe = $('iframe'); // or some other selector to get the iframe
//handle the code you need using the iframe variable.
```